# How to edit S3 files with python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working with python and I need to check and edit the content of some files stored in S3.
I need to check if they have a char o string. In that case, I have to replace this char/string.

For example:
I want to replace `;` with `.` in following file
File1.txt

```
This is an example;
```

After replace

File1.txt

```
This in an example.
```

Is there a way to do the replace without downloading the file?

Comment: Not unless you use something like s3fuse to mount the s3 bucket. https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse

Comment: You might also want to consider [versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html) these objects if you are going to download/edit/upload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.
I need to perform this action in a lambda and this is the result:

```py
    import boto3
    import json
    
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        file='test/data.csv'
        bucket = "my-bucket"
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=file )
        
        fileout = 'test/dout.txt'
        rout = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=fileout )
    
        
        data = []
        it = response['Body'].iter_lines()
        
        for i, line in enumerate(it):
            # Do the modification here
            modification_in_line = line.decode('utf-8').xxxxxxx  # xxxxxxx is the action
            data.append(modification_in_line)
    
        
        r = s3.put_object(
            Body='\n'.join(data), Bucket=bucket, Key=fileout,)
        
        
        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps(data),
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Objects in Amazon S3 are *immutable* (they cannot be changed).

I recommend that your code does the following:

- **Download** the file from Amazon S3 to local disk
- Perform edits on the local file
- **Upload** the file to Amazon S3 with the same Key (filename)